# Count consecutive elements in a list of a dataframe on cell level in new columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have the following df:

```
df6 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Sara',  'John', 'Jack'],
                   'places': ['UK,UK,UK,UK,US,CA', 'US,US,US,CA,CA,CA', 'Mexico,AUS,AUS,Mexico,Mexico']
                   })

df6
```

Looks like:

```
    name    places
0   Sara    UK,UK,UK,UK,US,CA
1   John    US,US,US,CA,CA,CA
2   Jack    Mexico,AUS,AUS,Mexico,Mexico
```

The places column only focuses on 5 countries. What I am trying to do is find the number of **consecutive visits** to each country. So basically the output will be like:

```
    name    UK   US   CA   Mexico   AUS    
0   Sara    4    0    0       0      0
1   John    0    3    3       0      0  
2   Jack    0    0    0       2      2
```

The steps I did so far is:

```
df6['consecutive'] = df6.places.map(lambda x: [Counter(group[1]) for group in groupby(x.split(','))])
```

This gives me a `list of dicts`:

```
    name    places                        consecutive
0   Sara    UK,UK,UK,UK,US,CA             [{'UK': 4}, {'US': 1}, {'CA': 1}]
1   John    US,US,US,CA,CA,CA             [{'US': 3}, {'CA': 3}]
2   Jack    Mexico,AUS,AUS,Mexico,Mexico  [{'Mexico': 1}, {'AUS': 2}, {'Mexico': 2}]
```

Now I stuck here on how to iterate over each cell in consecutive column to find `values > 1` per cell and reshape the df6 to the final output:

```
    name    UK   US   CA   Mexico   AUS    
0   Sara    4    0    0       0      0
1   John    0    3    3       0      0  
2   Jack    0    0    0       2      2
```

Comment: Do you just take the max consecutive value or the last? Jack has Mexico 1 and Mexico 2.

Comment: Values > 1 because in my data if the value is 1 it means only one visit so for Jack I am selecting Mexico 2 and AUS 2

Comment: Yes but if for Jack you had `Mexico, Mexico, Mexico, AUS, AUS, Mexico, Mexico`  what would you keep ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html#pandas-crosstab):

```py
df6["places"] = df6["places"].apply(lambda x: x.split(","))
df6 = df6.explode("places")

out = pd.crosstab(df6["name"], df6["places"])
out.index.name = None
out.columns.name = None
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
      AUS  CA  Mexico  UK  US
Jack    2   0       3   0   0
John    0   3       0   0   3
Sara    0   1       0   4   1
```

---

EDIT: To sum `consecutive` column (for consecutive values **> 1**):

```py
from itertools import groupby
from collections import Counter

df6["consecutive"] = df6.places.map(
    lambda x: [
        {k: v for k, v in Counter(group[1]).items() if v > 1}
        for group in groupby(x.split(","))
    ]
)

df6 = df6.explode("consecutive").reset_index(drop=True)
out = (
    pd.concat([df6, pd.DataFrame(df6.pop("consecutive").tolist())], axis=1)
    .groupby("name")
    .sum()
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
       UK   US   CA  AUS  Mexico
name                            
Jack  0.0  0.0  0.0  2.0     2.0
John  0.0  3.0  3.0  0.0     0.0
Sara  4.0  0.0  0.0  0.0     0.0
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej, your output shows the all visits to each country. I am looking for a way to find only `consecutive visits` that is why I used the `df6['consecutive'] = df6.places.map(lambda x: [Counter(group[1]) for group in groupby(x.split(','))])` to find the consecutive values based on the sorted comma separated list  in column`places`

Answer (score 1):

We can [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) `places`. Then take the [`groupby size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) to get the consecutive counts filter with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to include only visits greater than 1 consecutive. Then [`groupby sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) to reduce to a single row per name and [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) back to the original DataFrame:

```
places = df6["places"].str.split(',').explode()  # Each place in own row

df7 = df6[['name']].join(
    places.groupby(
        [df6['name'],  # Name
         places,  # Places
         # consecutive duplicates in separate groups
         places.ne(places.shift()).groupby(df6['name']).cumsum()]
    ).size()  # Count how many in each group
        .loc[lambda x: x > 1]  # Filter to include only > 1 visits
        .unstack(1, fill_value=0)  # Make places columns
        .groupby(level=0).sum(),  # Get single row per name
    on='name'  # join back on name column
)
```

`df7`:

```
   name  AUS  CA  Mexico  UK  US
0  Sara    0   0       0   4   0
1  John    0   3       0   0   3
2  Jack    2   0       2   0   0
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use pivot_table:

```
import pandas as pd

df6 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Sara',  'John', 'Jack'],
                   'places': ['UK,UK,UK,UK,US,CA', 'US,US,US,CA,CA,CA', 'Mexico,AUS,AUS,Mexico,Mexico']
               })

df6['places'] = df6.places.str.split(',')
df6 = df6.explode('places')
df6['lag_places'] = df6.places.shift(1)
df6 = df6.query('places == lag_places').pivot_table(index = 'name', columns = 'places',  aggfunc = 'count')
df6.loc[:, df6.columns != 'places'] = df6.loc[:, df6.columns != 'places'].apply(lambda x: x+1) # add 1 according to your definition
df6.columns = [x[1] for x in df6.columns]
df6.fillna(0, inplace = True)

#      AUS   CA  Mexico   UK   US
#name                            
#Jack  2.0  0.0     2.0  0.0  0.0
#John  0.0  3.0     0.0  0.0  3.0
#Sara  0.0  0.0     0.0  4.0  0.0
```